# Change Verbiage on WooCommerce Subscriptions Customer Facing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I'm looking to change the verbiage for the word "Suspend" to the word "Pause" on the customer-facing side of WooCommerce Subscriptions. I have the filter that pulls up the action buttons but I'm unsure of how to pull the specific action of "Suspend" and change it to the word "Pause".

Here is the filter.

```
apply_filters( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', $actions, $subscription );
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If you need more information I'm happy to provide what I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `wcs_view_subscription_actions` filter hook. this way. check below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'change_action_buttons_label', 10, 2 );
function change_action_buttons_label( $actions, $subscription ){
    if( isset( $actions['suspend'] ) ){
        $actions['suspend']['name'] = __( 'Pause', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' );
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much!